# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in TeachersController#show and SQLite3::SQLException: no such column Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I got two tables, one is called `Teacher`, the other is called `Teacher_Type`.
A `Teacher` can have many `Teach_Types` i.e. Mr John Smith is a Module Leader, a Tutor and also a Lecturer (3 teacher types).

I have the following associations between them and their respective model:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :teacher_types
 attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :teacher_type_ids

class TeacherType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers
  attr_accessible :title
end
```

So now when I try to create a new `Teacher` with a number of `Teacher_Types` attached to it, like so:
[image: SCreenshot1]

However when I press the "Create Teacher" button, I get the following error message:

[image]

I created some `Teachers` before, but left the `Teacher_Types` empty, so even when I try to go to `localhost:3000/teachers/3`, I get the following error message (included the SQLite browser to see what's inside the `Teachers` table)

[image]

So I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here....

Is my association incorrect?

Comment: do u have `teachers_teacher_types` or `teacher_types_teachers` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create table called `teachers_teacher_types`

```
class CreateTeachersTeacherTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :teachers_teacher_types, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer  :teacher_id
      t.integer :teacher_type_id
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: So do I need to change anything with my associations? i.e. the `belongs_to_and_has_many` on both models?

Comment: No, your associations are correct.. you have table `teachers_teacher_types` or `teacher_types_teachers`?

Comment: I just created `teacher_types_teachers` according to the error message, and it works. Thanks a lot ;-)

Comment: By the way, I need to be able to iterate through the array of `Teacher_Types` for the `Teacher`, however the following code doesn't seem to work:
`<%= @teacher.teacher_types.each { |type| type.title }%>`

All I get is the following:

**Teacher type:** `[#<TeacherType id: 2, title: "Tutor", created_at: "2013-03-07 13:07:55", updated_at: "2013-03-07 13:09:24">, #<TeacherType id: 3, title: "Lecturer", created_at: "2013-03-07 13:08:00", updated_at: "2013-03-07 13:08:39">]`

Comment: What is the problem?? I think its correct. You have two types `Tutor` and `Lecturer` for `@teacher`.

Comment: What I mean is that just want it to look like this for instance:
**Teacher Type:"** Tutor, Lecturer.
Any ideas?

Comment: `Teacher Type: <%= @teacher.teacher_types.map(&:title).to_sentence(:last_word_connector => ' and ')%>`

Comment: Wow, you seriously are good ;-)
Could you also be so kind as to explain why this worked i.e. using a `map`? I tried doing `@teacher.teacher_types.each {|t| t.tile}` but it didn't work. Any reason?

Comment: You are just looping. So its giving objects which are looped. To get array of title you can also use `collect`. `@teacher.teacher_types.collect{|t| t.tile}` and `@teacher.teacher_types.map{|t| t.tile}` is equivalent to `@teacher.teacher_types.map(&:title)`

Comment: so using the `map(&:title)` is just a shortcut version, right?

Comment: Oh by the way, the `(:last_word_connector => ' and ')` is not necessary, as the `to_sentence` function already deals with it, it's a really nice function, because if I have 3 teacher types, it displays it as: `Teacher, Lecturer and Module Leader`

Answer (score 0):

I Think your models should be something like:

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :teacher_types
   attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :teacher_type_ids
end

TeacherType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teachers
  attr_accessible :title
end

Try it if its correct for you???